# Unable to upload on cloudianry server in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am using ng-file-upload. I am getting CORS error from cloudinary server. I do not know what got wrong, i am pasting my code below

```
        Upload.upload({
          url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + credrentials["cloud_name"] + "/upload",
          fields: {
            cloud_name: credrentials["cloud_name"],
            api_key: credrentials["api_key"],
            signature: credrentials["signature"],
            timestamp: credrentials["timestamp"],
            //file: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/justask/image/upload/v1450094392/kfvu2lnh4pidjfb0b3vz.jpg'
          },
          file: file
      }).progress(function (e) {
        console.log("progress");
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log("success");
        $rootScope.photos = $rootScope.photos || [];
        data.context = {custom: {photo: $scope.title}};
        file.result = data;
        $rootScope.photos.push(data);
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        file.result = data;
      });
```

Comment: Are you trying with localhost?

Comment: Yes, I am running server on localhost.

Comment: Yes, this issue usually comes with the localhost. Either you should load your application using ip or make it live. I usually use xamp to run the application

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. I had enabled the http-interceptor which was sending Authorization request ,i have removed  & solved this issue.